# Let's get critical: Feb 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Salesforce Stack Exchange](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Can you override the single string parameter constructor for Exception?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23886/can-you-override-the-single-string-parameter-constructor-for-exception)

**Net Score: 20** (Excellent: 20, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Deploying Metadata to sandboxes using ant build](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22385/deploying-metadata-to-sandboxes-using-ant-build)

**Net Score: 14** (Excellent: 14, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Lead Conversion to Custom Object](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22846/lead-conversion-to-custom-object)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How do I upload a 'Document' sobject using the REST API?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22309/how-do-i-upload-a-document-sobject-using-the-rest-api)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Format of EmailMessage.ccAddress](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23582/format-of-emailmessage-ccaddress)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 16, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [how much i can customize salesforce report](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23386/how-much-i-can-customize-salesforce-report)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Is upsert properly ACID compliant?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23088/is-upsert-properly-acid-compliant)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [Workflow Execution order](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23479/workflow-execution-order)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Http Callout to Rest API from apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22262/http-callout-in-rest-api)

**Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 9)

---

- [unable to find jar files please some one help](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23158/unable-to-find-jar-files-please-some-one-help)

**Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 13, Needs Improvement: 7)

---